# Read/Write C# array from C++ application

Tags: c#, c++

Previously I had a c++ console application and I rewrote everything to C# WPF application so I have now UI, but I cant figure out how to get a correct offset (pointer) to change or read a value via C++ application.

In c++ it was so easy to get address

```
uint32_t check = 0xABCD;    
uint64_t add[1];
add[0] = (uintptr_t)&check;   
printf("address: 0x%I64x\n", (uint64_t)&add[0] - (uint64_t)GetModuleHandle(NULL));
```

and then from another program I was able to read/write **add**.
Tried with garbage collector, but everytime address changes + wrong address. Also NativeMemory was not working because I can not use unsafe code.

```
public static IntPtr[] add = new IntPtr[1];
protected static int check = 0xABCD;

public static void SomeFunction()
{
GCHandle check_handle = GCHandle.Alloc(check, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr check_ptr = check_handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
add[0] = check_ptr;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate
 {
 if (long.TryParse(add[0].ToString(), out long add0))
 {
    long offset_addr = (long)add[0] - (long)GetModuleHandle(null);
    a.add_offset_textbox.Text = "0x" + offset_addr.ToString("X");
 }
 }));
}
```

Comment: I haven't needed to do any interop with C# for years, but if I recall, C# provides COM interfaces for all its datatypes. It seems very surprising that you need to do any kind of memory hacks to interact with your C# program. Surely you would just acquire the appropriate object/interface and then go for it.

Comment: souldnt that be `=(long)add0` - in the c# code

Comment: @paddy it is NOT suprising if you consider the different memory models. Pinning may be required to prevent garbage collector from moving memory that C++ is refering to. COM is an option but a better interop is C++/cli. Introduction here : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes